# Insert record into SQL table based on values from another table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, insert, vba, recordset

I have a SQL database with an Access front end.  I am trying to get the employeeid from one table, and insert it, along with other values into another table.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am not getting any errors, and when I look at the values, they are there.  My insert command is just not working.  I also know that getting the employeeid from the other table is working.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Private Sub Command666_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim strSql, strsql2, strsql3 As String

Dim st As Date
Dim st2 As Date
Dim vempid, vworkcode As Integer
Dim vhours, vhours2 As Double
Dim vdtadd As Date

strSql = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployees"

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

rs.MoveFirst

Do While Not rs.EOF

    vempid = rs!EmployeeID
    vhours = 40
    vhours2 = 8
    vdtadd = Date
    vworkcode = 1

    st = DateAdd("m", 6, Date)
    st2 = DateAdd("m", 7, Date)

    If rs!StartDate >= st And rs!StartDate < st2 Then

        strsql2 = "Insert into tblTimeAvailable (EmployeeID, NoofHours, DateAdded, WorkCode) values (@vempid, @vhours, @vdtadd, @vWorkCode)"
        db.Execute strsql2
    Else

        If rs!StartDate >= st2 Then

            strsql3 = "Insert into tblTimeAvailable (EmployeeID, NoofHours, DateAdded, WorkCode) values (@vempid, @vhours2, @vdtadd, @vWorkCode)"
            db.Execute strsql3
        End If

    End If


    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
MsgBox ("Sick Time added")
```

End Sub

Comment: Maybe neither of the conditions required for issuing the Insert are true.   I would run a profiler trace on the SQL server to see what, if any, command is being issued.

Comment: Your `INSERT` statements are parameter queries, but you don't supply values for those parameters when you execute them.  Doesn't Access complain about the missing parameter values?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to verify that either `db.Execute strsql2` or `db.Execute strsql3` is actually run?

Comment: Thanks guys!  You made me think and my date comparisons were off.  Also, it wouldn't give me the values in the insert, so I just worded it different.  Should I post my new code with the answer?  But you guys were the ones that made it happen!